# Convert String characters to Int

Tags: swift

I already know you can convert a string to int doing this:

```swift
var intVal: Int = Int(numberString)!
```

The question is, I'm trying to convert each character, doing this:

```swift
for digitChar in numberString.characters
{
    let digit: Int = Int(digitChar)
}
```

But when I try to do this, I the following error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(String.CharacterView._Element)'

So, how can I achieve this? I tried a lot of different ways but I simply can't convert the characters making the string, to Int.

Comment: *Hint:* Character -> String -> Int

Comment: Well your hint is more like an answer. Haha i though that swift could handle this by himself. If you want to make that an answer i'll upvote it. :)

Comment: @Adrian Swift steers clear of implicit behaviour like in C# and C++. It could be done, but it's purposely avoided.

Comment: @MartinR I would leave your answer up IMO – the `flatMap(_:)` suggestion is quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the Character to a String first:

```
for c in numbers.text.characters {
    if let digit = Int(String(c)) {
        print(digit)
    } else {
        // Invalid input
    }
}
```

or

```
let allDigits = numbers.text.characters.flatMap { Int(String($0)) }
```

(which silently drops non-digit characters).

Comment: I have to wait 4 min before i can accept the answer but now i have a doubt, where can i find this "hierarchy"? I would never know that you had to convert character to string and then to int.

Comment: @Adrian: The [Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift) is fully documented. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/int) you'll find that Int can be initialized from a String (but not from Character).

Comment: @Adrian: You can also "option-click" on `Int` or on `import Swift` in the Xcode source editor to explore the Swift world.